# disable public ip of GCE vm in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I have ansible playbook for for GCE VM creation. This playbook launch GCE VM with public ip address.
How to launch my GCE vm without public ip address.?

I'm new to ansible.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are using GCE Ansisble module for VM creation. According to GCE module [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/gce_module.html#gce-module), the module has a parameter named `external_ip`. Set it to `none` if you don't want any public IP address assigned to your VM.

> **external_ip:**
>   type of external ip, ephemeral by default; alternatively, a fixed gce ip or ip name can be given. Specify 'none' if no external ip is desired.

**Example:**

```
- gce:
  instance_names: my-test-instance1
  zone: us-central1-a
  machine_type: n1-standard-1
  external_ip: none
  image: debian-8
  state: present
  service_account_email: "your-sa@your-project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  credentials_file: "/path/to/your-key.json"
  project_id: "your-project-name"
  disk_size: 32
```

Comment: Hey Kanwar Saad,
Thanks for your reply . You are right . I've already got this and resolved the issue .
It should be---- external_ip: 'none'

Thanks & Regards
Ram